# how to thoroughly remove JQPlot Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

Do you know how to thoroughly remove/clean JQPlot chart. Here is my code to clean it:

```
     $j("#reset").click(function() {

                                                  $j("#chart").empty();
                                                        if (plot1) {

                                                            plot1 = null;
                                                        }


                                            });
```

when I click reset button, the chart can be removed from my page, but when I choose new conditions from drop down lists to generate new chart, the old chart will overlap with the new chart, like this image showed[image]
Do you know how to truly clean the old chart? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use `redraw` method.

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#jqPlot.redraw

Answer (score 1):

You can redraw it with empty values using :

```
$.("#reset").click(function(){
  if(plot1){
    plot1 = $.jqplot('chart', [[[]]], {});
    plot1.redraw();
  }
});
```

Please see working example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/qRnmd/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed your step, but the old chart still overlapped with the new one,so weird...

Comment: Ok can you give us a bit more about your chart definition?

Answer (score 1):

My method is "expensive" but works for me. Use `.remove()`:

```
if ($("#chart").length) {
    $("#chart1").remove();
} else {
    $(parent).append("<div id=\"chart1\"></div>");
}
// put $.jqplot below here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the destroy method.
e.g.

```
if (C.chart != null) {
    C.chart.destroy();
    C.chart = null;
}
C.chart = $.jqplot("chart", chartData, {
```